# Who is playing the projector at Mrs. Glenn's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-nice-guys

In The Nice Guys (2016), Mrs. Glenn always claims that she has seen Misty appearing at her window in a pinstripe jacket, despite March insisting that Misty is dead.

In the final scenes, we understood that Mrs. Glenn only saw Misty through the image projected on her window.

Who is playing the projector at Mrs. Glenn House?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was explained that it was Amelia, confirming that it was the movie that they made and wanted to use at the auto industry/trade show.

That also explains why her car was seen.

Comment: If anyone were trying to avoid this info, they wouldn't have clicked on the question ;)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Erring on the side of caution. :D